# Similar triangle inside a right triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

[image]

$\angle BAC = \pi/2$, $A', B', C'$ are on the sides or on the extensions of the sides $BC, CA, AB$ respectively, $\triangle ABC \sim \triangle A'B'C'$.

Prove (or disprove) that $A'$ is the midpoint of $BC$.

For a hint, see the comment under [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2827798).

Comment: That question was deleted, here's a snapshot: https://i.imgur.com/MKetmuG.png.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true!

$C'A'B'A$ can be inscribed in a circle, hence $\angle A'AB'=\angle A'C'B'=\angle A'CB'$. This implies that $AA'=A'C$

Similarly, you get that $AA'=BA'$ by looking at another pair of equal angles. QED

Comment: Nice, this is probably the cleanest way. My idea was to start with $B'C' \parallel BC$, then rotating the lines $A'B'$ and $A'C'$ by $\phi$ around $A'$ gives a new triangle with $A'B'' = A'B' \sec \phi, A'C'' = A'C' \sec \phi$, therefore similar to the unrotated triangle.