# Finding similar scalene triangles

Tags: geometry, triangles

Given a scalene triangle $P$, does there exist a similar scalene triangle $P'$, such that when $P'$ is put inside $P$, all three of $P'$ vertices's touch all three of the inner edges of $P$?

If so, is there a function that you can use to find the **smallest** possible $P'$ that will still touch all of the inner edges of $P$?

Comment: What's wrong with just connecting the mid points?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: similar enclosed scalene triangle]

In reply to the first question, let $P$ be a scalene triangle $ABC$. Bisect its sides at $D$, $E$, $F$, and complete triangle $DEF$. Then by *VI, 2* of Euclid's *Elements*, $FE$, $ED$, $DF$ are parallel to $BC$, $AB$, $CA$, respectively, and therefore triangle $DEF$, which we may call $P'$, is similar to $P$.

It can be seen that$$P=4P'$$Whether $P'$ is the smallest (or largest?)  similar triangle with vertices lying on the sides of $\triangle ABC$ remains to be considered.

Answer (score 1):

With [this parametrization](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2831395/similar-triangle-inside-a-right-triangle#comment5873644_2831395) (the image link in the comment), the scale factor is $\sqrt{k^2 + 1/4}$.